# Need to get a value from a firebase database and store it in a local variable

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The game requires to keep a count of the number of games a user has played.
A var " gamesPlayed : Int " keeps track of that.
The problem arises when the user restarts the game and the value stored in the gamesPlayed is removed, I tried extracting the value of gamesPlayed from the database whenever the app starts and to assign it to the variable but it doesn't seem to work.

JSON

```
    `users
 K7g3KamKXfb8IlgqjEgAj9uQFGZ2
 game-1
 GAME-NUMBER: 1
 REACTION-TIME: .5
 SCORE: 10
 SWIPES: 10`
```

My code

```
var gamesPlayed :Int?
    var tempGamesPlayed :Int?
let userID = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: KEY_UID)
let getref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).queryOrderedByValue().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.exists() {
                          print("we have that snapshot, the id is \(snapshot.value!)")
                         self.tempGamesPlayed = snapshot.value(forKey: "GAME-NUMBER")
                    print("tempgames is \(self.tempGamesPlayed)")
                    } else {
                      print("we don't have that")
                }
            })
            if tempGamesPlayed == nil
            {
                gamesPlayed = 0

            }
            else
            {
                gamesPlayed = tempGamesPlayed!

            }
            gamesPlayed! += 1

            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).child("game-\(gamesPlayed!)")

            if swipes > 0
            {
            ref.updateChildValues([
                "SCORE": c,
                "SWIPES": swipes,
                "REACTION-TIME": reactTime,
                "GAME-NUMBER": gamesPlayed!
                ])
            }
            else
            {
                ref.updateChildValues([
                    "SCORE": 0,
                    "SWIPES": 0,
                    "REACTION-TIME": 0,
                    "GAME-NUMBER": gamesPlayed!
                    ])
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated!